# Run a query and pick out a result fast w/ a count of the rows before it?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a leaderboard esque ranking system for a website based on stats in an sql database. However, I want to make it so a user can enter their username and it will display 5 ranks less and 5 ranks more than they are.

I am not sure how to do this because the table I want to get the information from is about 123,000 rows long, and as you can imagine, this would take a very long time to run through. I was wondering if there was an easy way to have it search through the rows, logging the # of rows until it reaches x row, then split out the row number. Also possibly if you can be bothered, include information on how I would go about getting the rows that are higher and lower in that query. Thanks :)

For other info, this is hoping to be done with sql and php

To give a better example of what i want to do with this: I want to find the result number of a specific row that meets specific criteria, in this case, a name, then use that number to get the data around it. And i would rather be able to get the result # without having to scan through all of the results.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because i wasn't sure where to start with this with my limited knowledge of sql, and I use MYSQL

Comment: How is the rank stored?  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you should be storing the rank as a separate column.

Comment: I'm not storing the rank under the issue that the rank can easily fluctuate based on statistics. The way i was orignally doing the rankings was `SELECT * FROM [table] ORDER BY [row] DESC`. This would work well if it wasn't for the 123,000 rows that it may take to find the person's username..

Comment: in most similar setups, afaik, rank is assigned to another column/table and then updated on a regular basis such as hourly/daily by a cron script. This is the only method I know of to get such rank reliably without iterating.

Comment: I hope that I can find a way not to do this, because it makes it less enjoyable for the users, as I want/wish they will be able to see their stats go up in real time. :/

Comment: Updated it to better give an example of what i want

Comment: If you put an index on the table, you shouldn't have any problem accessing the records.

Comment: Without having the ranking order stored somewhere, the only way to do this is extremely inefficient.  I suggest having a cache table that has the user id, rank position, and rank score that gets updated by a trigger or a query that gets run every few seconds.

Comment: If it's updated by a query run every few seconds.. wouldn't that be laggy though? Also, my issue with storing the ranking order: I have 6+ leaderboards... I'm not sure how effective it would be to make that many tables..

Comment: The query might take a bit depending on what it does, but that option would need some testing to see if it's viable.  The other option of using a trigger would be good if your rankings are fairly simple (i.e. if each ladder is on a simple stat like points or kills) so you can just add to that specific entry in the cache without having to do a large query frequently.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very efficient, as even with an index on the `score` column it still involves a full table scan to create the ranking, but this will do what you want:

```sql
SELECT    allusers.rank, allusers.Name, allusers.Kills
FROM (
  SELECT   AgStats.Name,
           @t:=IF(score<=>@s,@t,@r) AS rank,
           @s:=AgStats.Kills AS Kills,
           @r:=@r+1
  FROM     AgStats, (SELECT @r:=0, @s:=NULL, @t:=NULL) init
  ORDER BY AgStats.Kills DESC
) allusers, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
  FROM   AgStats
  WHERE  Kills > (SELECT Kills FROM AgStats WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer')
) user
WHERE    ABS(allusers.rank-user.rank) <= 5
ORDER BY allusers.rank
```

Comment: My issue with this is that, as stated in the question, the table is 123,000 rows long, so doing a full table scan isn't an applicable option at this point.

Comment: Benchmark it before ruling it out.  You have rejected maintaining a cached rank, and I don't see any other way...

Comment: Your `row` is analogous to my `score`, not my `rank`.

Comment: It's saying to order by rank, where rank is non-existant. I'm not storing the ranks.

Comment: No.  `allusers.rank` is a column generated in the materialised `allusers` table by incrementing a user variable `@r` as the `scores` table is traversed in descending order of `score`.

Comment: I'll go benchmark it in the SQL database then and see how long it would take, then run the query through php and see if it still runs fast.

Comment: If there's a significant performance degradation between running a query in an interactive client and in PHP, then you have more serious problems at play than your query.

Comment: @VoidWhisperer: See my edit above, which also fixes the ranking of users with identical kills.

Comment: It seems I'm going to have to enforce a hard limit somewhere still, because the query executes very slowly at the last few rows if you do the whole db.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20537/discussion-between-voidwhisperer-and-eggyal)